Method calling using java interface generics parameter in JPYPE
I am new in Jpype trying few points.
Java Code :
public class TestImpl implements TestInteface{ // Some methods}

public class DriverClass {      

public void testMethod1(){ 
TestInterface test= new TestImpl();
this.testMethod2(test);
}

public void testMethod2(TestInterface test){ 
//Do Something
}
}

Above is replicating my current scenario. After Creating Jar file of above java code we tried to include it in JPYPE sample code to call testMethod2.

Start JVM
jpype.startJVM()

Adding Jar file for above code in Jpype
jpype.addClassPath(....)

Method calling from jpype
pkg= jpype.JPackage(pkgName)
testImpl= pkg.TestImpl
pkg.DriverClass.testMethod2(testImpl)


after calling testMethod2 , It will give exception as

No matching overloads found for static
pkg.DriverClass.testMethod2(testImpl), options are:
public void pkg.DriverClass.testMethod2(testInterface)

How can we call methods which are having interface as a parameter (generics) by passing Impls ? is there any other way in JPYPE
Note: Somehow I can not change the java implementation , so trying to understand the ways to use it as it is in JPYPE
